# A generic error occured in GDI+ while adding date and time into the saved picture

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I want to create a simple capture active window. So, I create it like the code below:

```
string _dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;

        try
        {
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                }

                bitmap.Save("D:/Test/Screenshot - " + _dateTime + " -.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("Success!", "Success", 1);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SystemManager.ShowMessageBox("There is an unexpected error: " + ex.Message, "Error", 3);
        }
    }
```

But the code above give an error:

`A generic error occured in GDI+`

But once I changed the saved image into this:

```
bitmap.Save("D:/Test/Screenshot.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It successfully capture the image.

My question is: Do it cannot add the date and time into the saved image?

So the format will be like this:

`Screenshot - 21/01/2015 -.jpg`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: "Screenshot - 21/01/2015 -.jpg" means that you are trying to save the file "2015 -.jpg" in the folder "Screenshot - 21", with the subfolder "01"...

Comment: Thank you @DanByström, solved already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bitmap.Save()` does not construct sub directories and this is why you are getting the error.

When you save your bitmap as "Screenshot - 21/01/2015 -.jpg" It will assume that `/` is a directory separator and it will try to construct the path accordingly.

An easy way is to construct your date time with some other character like a `-` for example.